# Javascript Android - plot ECG graph without using 3rd party API's

Tags: java, javascript, android

I need to plot an ECG graph using Javascript without using any API's. I will get a response (graph-co-ordinates) from the server and i have to plot a graph. It can be done in Javascript "CANVAS" or "SVG". But i dont know where to start. Give me some guidance for this criteria.

Comment: Why without any api's?

Comment: If i am coding it. I can mold it and reuse. But with API its not possible i think so !!!!

Comment: Most APIs are designed very flexible so they can fit best to your needs. Sometimes there are missing features but that's not most of the time. But you can also decide to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Use an API, and hours of work have already been done for you. Plenty mistakes have been made and learned from. You save yourself lots of work. Given the nature of your plots, choose your library based on maturity, how well the date-time axis is supported and on if you can easily add a raster to the canvas.

A good candidate, seems to me, is [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/), if the [licence](http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html) (Creative Commons non-commercial) agrees with you.

Once you have chosen your library, first plot the simplest sample plot using their demos or tutorial.

Then pick a couple examples from the demo or tutorial that demonstrate aspects of your ECG plots (date time axis, raster, style/colors, splines?)

Then move on to showing sample data from one of your ECGs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tiny but useful ECG chart display tool. https://github.com/sergey-chuvayev/ecg_display_plugin